# Общий контрол для нескольких страниц (MUI 1.0.9)

Tags: .net, wpf

Делаю приложение на WPF с использованием [Modern UI framework](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui), необходимо сделать 1 контрол, который не будет изменятся при переключении между страницами. Подскажите как лучше всего это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение - необходимо создать `usercontrol` необходимого контрола и использовать его для всех страниц, а переход страниц изменить напрямую через `mui`.